# ¿Como corregir el fallo al detectar el estado del check en un DataGridView?

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Tengo el siguiente metodo que detecta cuando se marco o desmarco una casilla en un `datagridview`:

```
        private void DgvListarClientes_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridView DetectarCheck = (DataGridView)sender;

        if (DetectarCheck.Columns[e.ColumnIndex] is DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn && e.RowIndex >= 0)
        {
            int TotalDeFilas = dgvListarClientes.Rows.Count;

            // invierto el estado del check seleccionado debido a que no se actualiza en el momento de marcarlo.
            if (dgvListarClientes.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[5].Value != null)
            {
                if (!(bool)dgvListarClientes.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[5].Value)
                {
                    ClientesDelPedido.RemoveAll(I => I == (int)dgvListarClientes.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value);
                    ClientesDelPedido.Add((int)dgvListarClientes.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value);
                }
                else
                {
                    ClientesDelPedido.RemoveAll(I => I == (int)dgvListarClientes.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value);
                }
            }

            lblResultadoTotalClientes.Text = Convert.ToString(ClientesDelPedido.Count);
        }
    }
```

Y como pueden observar, tengo que invertir el estado del `check` debido a que mientras ocurre el `evento` se lo toma como el estado que tenia inicialmente. El problema, es que si marco nuevamente **el mismo `check` que acabe de marcar**, el `evento` si me lo toma como el estado final que tendria, por lo que el inversor del estado, ahora envesde ayudarme, me genera un fallo logico. No quiero andar creando variables en cada `datagridview` para que detecten si la ultima columna marcada fue la misma que marco ahora. ¿Hay alguna forma de corregir este error?

En la siguiente imagen muestro como marque un `check`, y posteriormente marque y desmarque un mismo `check`, pero el contador no elimino este ultimo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Quizas estes buscando algo parecido a esto: [How to detect DataGridView CheckBox event change?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11843488)

Comment: Puntee tu pregunta por que es una pregunta muy esclarecedora, pasa mucho en las columnas de tipo ´DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn´ y ´DataGridViewComboBoxColumn´ y además en columnas definidas por el desarrollador. Siempre se tiende a hacer referencia a la propiedad ´Value´ de la celda, pero en estos casos el valor de la propiedad ´EditedFormattedValue´ hace referencia al valor del control de edición interno de la celda ´IDataGridViewEditingContro´. Coloque una respuesta con la solución, haciendo referencia a la propiedad ´EditedFormattedValue´.

Answer (score 0):

Que tal? Creo que con este código puede que funcione como necesitas...

Si no me equivoco, lo que te faltaba era asignar el valor contrario a la fila actual.

Espero que te ayude,
Un saludo!!

```
private void DgvListarClientes_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridView DetectarCheck = (DataGridView)sender;
    int columnaSelect = 1;

    if (DetectarCheck.Columns[e.ColumnIndex] is DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn && e.RowIndex >= 0)
    {
        bool seleccionado = false;
        int valor = (int)DgvListarClientes.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value;

        if (DgvListarClientes.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[columnaSelect].Value == null) seleccionado = false;
        else seleccionado = (bool)DgvListarClientes.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[columnaSelect].Value;

        ClientesDelPedido.RemoveAll(I => I == valor);

        if (!seleccionado) ClientesDelPedido.Add(valor);

        DgvListarClientes.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[columnaSelect].Value = !seleccionado; // Invertimos el valor
        lblResultadoTotalClientes.Text = Convert.ToString(ClientesDelPedido.Count);
    }
}
```

Comment: Apenas pueda lo probaré y te la marcaré como respuesta si funciono.

Answer (score 0):

La solución a tu código es hacer referencia a la propiedad del `IDataGridViewEditingControl` de la celda lo puedes lograr capturando la propiedad `EditedFormattedValue` esta si estaría actualizada al momento de producirse el evento, tu código quedaría como sigue:

```
    private void DgvListarClientes_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{

DataGridView DetectarCheck = (DataGridView)sender;

    if (DetectarCheck.Columns[e.ColumnIndex] is DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn && e.RowIndex >= 0)
    {
        int TotalDeFilas = dgvListarClientes.Rows.Count;


        if (dgvListarClientes.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[5].EditedFormattedValue != null)
        {
           //ya no hay que invertir el valor del estado del check
            if ((bool)dgvListarClientes.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[5].EditedFormattedValue)
            {
                ClientesDelPedido.RemoveAll(I => I == (int)dgvListarClientes.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value);
                ClientesDelPedido.Add((int)dgvListarClientes.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value);
            }
            else
            {
                ClientesDelPedido.RemoveAll(I => I == (int)dgvListarClientes.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value);
            }
        }

        lblResultadoTotalClientes.Text = Convert.ToString(ClientesDelPedido.Count);
    }
}
```

Con ese cambio queda resuelto tu problema.

Comment: @Orion Te pido que pruebes esta solución, estoy seguro que funciona, lo he probado en múltiples ocasiones y de antemano te agradecería que puntearas mi respuesta, seria un estimulo para mi, pues soy usuario nuevo y además desarrollador autodidacta.